# How could I get files from a docker container running the official etcd image if there is no shell?

Tags: docker, etcd

I have a docker container that is running the etcd docker image by CoreOS which can be found here: https://quay.io/repository/coreos/etcd. What I want to do is copy all the files that are saved in etcd's data directory locally.  I tried to connect to the container using `docker exec -it etcd /bin/sh` but it seems like there is no shell (`/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`) on there or at least it can't be found on the `$PATH` variable.  How can I either get onto the image or get all the data files inside of etcd copied locally?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the contents of an image easily:

`docker export <CONTAINER ID> > /some_file.tar`

Ideally you should use volumes so that all your data is stored outside the container. Then you can access those files like any other file.

Answer (score 0):

Docker has the [cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command for copying files between container and host:

```
docker cp <id>:/container/source /host/destination
```

You specify the container ID or name in the source, and you can flip the command round to copy from your host into the container:

```
docker cp /host/source <id>:/container/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

the bin folder is empty. but the `etcdctl` is in the `/usr/local/bin/` folder.

so you can try:

```bash
docker exec -it <container_id> /usr/local/bin/etcdctl
docker exec -it <container_id> /usr/local/bin/etcdctl put foo "hello"
docker exec -it <container_id> /usr/local/bin/etcdctl get foo
```